# CSS ignores margin-right when the div is longer than 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a div that stretches longer than 100%. I am trying to create a container div around it but when I set the margin left and right to 50% the container div doesn't even seem to stretch all the way. It sort of works for the smaller div but it doesn't work for the longer div.

The margin-left seems to work fine but on the right side of the first div there is no margin.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 50px 50px; padding-right: 40px;">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;color: #7a7a7a;background: #dedede;border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;font-family:;display: inline-block;min-width: 100%;">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap">
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div style="width: 10px; margin: 0 100px; white-space: normal;">This is a div heheheh</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: gray; margin-top: 10px;">This is another div</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a scratchpad fiddle
http://scratchpad.io/foregoing-mitten-6881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display:inline-block` to the parent `div`

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 40px;margin: 50px 50px;display:inline-block">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;color: #7a7a7a;background: #dedede;border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;font-family:;display: inline-block;min-width: 100%;">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap">
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div style="width: 10px; margin: 0 100px; white-space: normal;">This is a div heheheh</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: gray; margin-top: 10px;">This is another div</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that

```html
<html>

    <body>
        <div style="margin: 50px 50px; padding-right: 40px;">
            <div style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;color: #7a7a7a;background: #dedede;border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;font-family;">
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div style="width: 10px; margin: 0 100px; white-space: normal;">This is a div heheheh</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
                <div>oneon e saf </div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>This is a div</div>
            </div>

            <div style="background-color: gray; margin-top: 10px;">This is another div</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS Your `container` div `overflow:auto;`

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 50px 50px; padding-right: 40px; overflow:auto;">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;color: #7a7a7a;background: #dedede;border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;font-family:;display: inline-block;min-width: 100%;">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap">
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div style="width: 10px; margin: 0 100px; white-space: normal;">This is a div heheheh</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
        <div>oneon e saf </div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a div</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: gray; margin-top: 10px;">This is another div</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, flex items will all try to fit onto one line. You can change that and allow the items to wrap as needed with this property.

Try to use flex-wrap: wrap
source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/